# Eventbrite XML Search not working

Tags: xml, search, eventbrite

I've been using:
https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_search?...

...for quite sometime now, and the last time the search worked it was approx 3pm  CST - Nov 6 2012.

The cron has been running every 15 min for the past 9 months but now when the search happens, it says that there is no event.  (Event doesn't happen for another 2 weeks)

Anyone else having this issue?

/Roger

Comment: same issue here (still). does your problem still exist?